# Where is KDE wallet database/files stored?

Tags: linux, kde, password-management

I looked everywhere and couldn't find where KDE Wallet information is stored. I would like to back it up but `kwallet-query` and `kwalletcli` doesn't seem to be able to export everything. Anyone has any idea?

PS.: I know that KDE Wallet Manager can export the database but that would be through the GUI. I'm looking for something that can be automated.

Comment: Hi, `kwalletcli` author here: the KWallet API does not have a method to export, unfortunately. I looked for it some time ago but it is a very bare-minimum API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that wallet files are stored inside `$XDG_DATA_HOME/kwalletd` which defaults to `$HOME/.local/share/kwalletd`.

[source](https://github.com/KDE/kwallet/blob/98913c4602b695847c495051eac34063a8c06173/src/runtime/kwalletd/backend/kwalletbackend.cc#L85)

Comment: That’s interesting. I don’t have the env variable $XDG_DATA_HOME but I have a kdewallet.kwl in that folder. I will try restoring it on another machine and if all goes well I back up that folder. Thanks